# Problems with creating a Yarn lock for nuxt because of a symlink missing?

Tags: nuxt.js, yarnpkg, symlink, lockfile

I'm not able to install a project with yarn anymore due to an error I get. It's preventing my local machine to create a lock file. I've been googling for half a day now and I'm getting desperate.

This is the response I get in the terminal:

[image]

When I install the project via `NPM install` and then run command `Yarn dev/build/generate` everything seems to be working fine.

I'm a total noob with Yarn so please bear with me.

Comment: try to run these commands to cleanup your deps `rm -rf node_modules yarn.lock && yarn cache clean && yarn`

Comment: Hi Nicolas thank you for your help. I just ran the commands above and the same error is coming up. I have the feeling that my yarn package manager is screwed up (if that makes any sense).
For example, i am not able to yarn add/remove packages any more